# The timeline should show who tagged a Collectives answer as recommended

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, collectives, moderator-tools, timeline

The moderation team has noticed that neither the moderator tools, nor the post timeline, indicates who tagged an answer in a Collective as recommended (technically called a post notice in the system). [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71320395/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries&filter=flags) (link is 10k+ only since the post has been deleted)

[image: Who took this action?]

The "Twilio" link takes you to [the Twilio Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/twilio). While the [list of people who could take this action is short](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/twilio?tab=members&ActiveRole=OnlyPartners&Page=1), that information should still be available to the public and the moderation team.

Comment: If the product team would prefer that it not be publicly accessible for whatever reason, it should at *least* be viewable by moderators.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have made some improvements on the timeline and revision pages that should allow you to see the recommending user going forward.

Unfortunately, a portion of the data cannot be backfilled due to previous technical decisions.

Posted by Recognized Member/Admin:
[image: Posted by Recognized Member/Admin]

Recommendation added and removed:
[image: Recommendation added and removed]

Answer (score 11):

We'll be adding the attribution, and it will look like this:
[image: Recommended answer attribution to be added]